# JQuery Array with multiple arrays mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mapping

Goodday,

I am stuck at the following crossroad. I have multiple array's nested inside one master array:

```
var masterArray = [['Phone','Town'],['0612345678','New York']];
```

Now i need to build a table and map 'Phone' with '0612345678' and 'Town' with 'New York'. So it should look like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Phone</td><td>0612345678</td></tr>
<tr><td>Town</td><td>New York</td></tr>
</table>
```

With $.each i can't seem tot map the right pairs.
How can I build a table with jquery from that masterArray object.

I hope someone can help me out with this problem.

Greetings,

Robert

Comment: Is that the full length of array? If not show repeating structure

Comment: But `masterArray` has always 2 elements and each element is always an array with 2 strings? If not, which is the general structure of  `masterArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [JSFiddle with the demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/aforni/544vxpho/).

Given the following HTML:

```
<table id='table'></table>
```

You can build the table with the following code:

```
var masterArray = [
    ['Phone', 'Town'],
    ['0612345678', 'New York']
];

var $table = $('#table'),
    $tr, $td;

for (var i = 0; i < masterArray[0].length; i++) {
    $tr = $('<tr>');
    for (var j = 0; j < masterArray.length; j++) {
        $td = $('<td>').text(masterArray[j][i]);
        $tr.append($td);

    }
    $table.append($tr);
}
```

Let me explain it.

I suppose that all the arrays inside `masterArray` have the same length, so in the external loop I create the single `<tr>` rows. The number of rows in equal to the number of element of the inner arrays:

```
for (var i = 0; i < masterArray[0].length; i++) {
```

In the inner loop:

```
for (var j = 0; j < masterArray.length; j++) {
```

I create the single `<td>` for the given row. Pay attention to:

```
$td = $('<td>').text(masterArray[j][i]);
```

To write the content inside the newly created `<td>` I inverted the indexes of `masterArray`. In this way I can the the i-th element of each array contained inside `masterArray`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It's a very nice short notation, good job!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var masterArray = [['Phone','Town'],['0612345678','New York']];

function buildTable(data, selector) {
  var $parent = $(document.body);
  // If given a selector, append to that.
  if (selector != null && $(selector).length > 0) {
      $parent = $(selector);
  }

  // Create table.
  var $table = $('<table>');
  
  // Treat items in masterArray as column
  $.each(masterArray, function(column, subArray) {

    // Treat items in subArray as row.
    $.each(subArray, function(row, data) {

      // Keep create row until the nth row can be found.
      while ($table.find('tr').eq(row).length === 0) {
        $table.append('<tr>');
      }

      // Append td with data to target row.
      $('<td>').text(data).appendTo($table.find('tr').eq(row));
    });
  });
  
  // Append to targetElement
  $table.appendTo($parent); 
}

buildTable(masterArray);
```

```css
table, td {
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```